# Scrapy: How to properly create scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse object based on url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I write a scrapy spider to scrape data from a webpage which has several subpages. Each of them also has several subpages etc. I want to visit all of the sub-sub-...-pages and take specific information from it.

To go deeper and deeper I want to query subsequent subpages with xpath() to get links and enter them. But to use xpath I need an object of `scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse` class. Therefore I write:

```py
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

new_response =  HtmlResponse(url=subpage_url)
```

But when I do an xpath query on such an object I don't get what I should get, just an empty list. What I suspect is that I didn't specify 'body' argument in `HtmlResponse()`. But the body is hidden in HTML from `subpage_url` and I want to get it from the subpage. Am I doing something incorrent, or is there any better way to get HTML from a subpage with known URL to xpath-query this HTML?

Comment: You seem to be using Scrapy as if it were the Requests library or similar. I recommend that you complete the Scrapy tutorial first.

Comment: Right, maybe I should try different approach using Scrapy or switch to requests/beautiful soup. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how BeautifulSoup would work. Use link extractor to go to the next page and click on items you want. Use xpath to extract the content you want. This is not how scrapy is used.